# Is there a way to debug Conflicting partition column names detected

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

Hey I am reading a big parquet file with 4 partitions schema using `spark.read.parquet()` with Glue 4.0 from an s3 bucket and I got this error

```
An error occurred while calling o143.parquet. assertion failed: Conflicting partition column names detected:
```

Is there a straightforward way to debug this error and find out which folder exactly has an inconsistency issue? as the parquet is pretty big to check every partition folder manually

or is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: This error mainly occurs if there are conflicting partition column names in your Parquet file, which means that two or more partition directories have different values for the same partition column. Mostly due to a data inconsistency issue, where the data in your source system has changed over time, causing different values to be written to the same partition column.

Comment: @DipanjanMallick Fully aware of why this happen but in my case, I got too much data and one of the partitions is date so many years and days to look up manually, I am just asking if there is away de debug this faster

Comment: One possible faster way to debug that I can think of is by setting `spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled` to `false` which will force spark to identify the partition columns as `string`. However, it may not work for all cases, especially if your Parquet file has a complex schema or nested structures.

Answer (score 0):

#You can use glue auto infer schema option

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).